# Formatting data for clogit model

Tags: r, excel

I have a survey with 53 respondents answering 8 questions each.

Currently it's in an Excel document in the format:

Person # | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 | Q7 | Q8

Each question had three possible responses, "1", "2", or "3". For a given person, each question has a single number indicating the response.

I need to transform the answers from each person into one long column vector with responses coded in binary for each of the three choices. So for each person, there should be 24 rows (3 for each question), and for each question, there should be one row with a 1 (indicating the choice that was made) and two rows with 0's.

I've tried doing this in Excel and in R and cannot figure out how to do it without manually entering each value.

Please tell me there's a better way?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with VBA?

Comment: @chrisneilsen If I could I would, but I could type it all in manually in the time it would take me to figure out how to do it with VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See explanation of code as inline comments

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim wsSource  As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim vSource As Variant

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    '--> adjust to suit your needs
    ' set up source and destination references
    Set wsSource = Worksheets("SourceData")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("DestData")

    '--> adjust to suit your needs
    ' Assumes source data has header in row 1, names in column A and responces in B..I
    With wsSource
        Set rSource = .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    '--> adjust to suit your needs
    ' Assumes generated data starts as cell A1
    Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Get Source data
    vSource = rSource.Value

    ' Size Destination data array
    ReDim vDest(1 To UBound(vSource, 1) * 24, 1 To 2)

    ' Generate reformated data
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSource, 1) ' For each Person
        For j = 1 To 24 ' Add person name
            vDest((i - 1) * 24 + j, 1) = vSource(i, 1)
        Next
        For j = 1 To 8 ' Code 8 results
            vDest((i - 1) * 24 + (j - 1) * 3 + 1, 2) = IIf(vSource(i, j + 1) = 1, 1, 0)
            vDest((i - 1) * 24 + (j - 1) * 3 + 2, 2) = IIf(vSource(i, j + 1) = 2, 1, 0)
            vDest((i - 1) * 24 + (j - 1) * 3 + 3, 2) = IIf(vSource(i, j + 1) = 3, 1, 0)
        Next
    Next

    ' Place result on sheet
    rDest.Resize(UBound(vDest, 1), UBound(vDest, 2)) = vDest

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! I'm going to have to dig in to this when I have the chance to really understand how to reproduce something like it.